# Multiple columns from aggregate function, but apply only to rows matching a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sample dataset:

```
+----------+---------+-----+
| order_id | prod_id | qty |
+----------+---------+-----+
|        1 |       1 |   2 |
|        1 |       1 |   4 |
|        1 |       3 |   1 |
|        2 |       1 |   1 |
|        2 |       2 |   2 |
|        3 |       4 |   1 |
|        3 |       4 |   2 |
|        3 |       2 |   3 |
|        3 |       3 |   5 |
|        4 |       1 |   2 |
|        4 |       2 |   3 |
|        4 |       3 |   3 |
|        4 |       4 |   3 |
|        4 |       6 |   2 |
+----------+---------+-----+
```

What I'm trying to do is build a "report" view, that will aggregate *certain* totals based on the product code. So for example, I want one column with totals by order for product code 1, another column with aggregate total for products 2 and 3, and one for product code 4 and 6.

Note that the values for the product codes are coming from a product class table, so I'm actually looking to get all products in class 1, which would be product 1, then all products in class 2, which would be products 2 and 3, and then all products in class 3, which would be products 4 and 6.

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| order_id | c1_tot | c2_tot | c3_tot |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|        1 |      6 |      1 |      0 |
|        2 |      1 |      2 |      0 |
|        3 |      0 |      8 |      3 |
|        4 |      2 |      6 |      5 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I can do this for *one column* using a WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT 
    [order_id],
    SUM([qty]) AS [c2]
FROM [orders]
WHERE [prod_id] IN (SELECT [id] FROM [product_class] WHERE [class] = 2)
GROUP BY [order_id]
```

The other approach I came up with was a stored function, but this seems a long-winded way to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [order_id],
    total_products_by_class([order_id],1) AS [c1_tot],
    total_products_by_class([order_id],2) AS [c2_tot],
    total_products_by_class([order_id],3) AS [c3_tot]
FROM [orders]
```

I suspect something could theoretically be done with analytic functions?...

Is there a way to do this without a stored function in something suitable for a view?

**Update:** make clearer about need to pull in values for products from a subquery.

Comment: You can use `CASE WHEN ... END` statement to do what you need.

Comment: Ok, that's a good start, but where would I put the `CASE` statements? I'd need to do something like `CASE WHEN [prod_id] = 1 THEN SUM([qty]) ELSE  0 END AS [p1_tot]`... No, I think that's going nowhere fast.

Comment: You can put `SUM(CASE WHEN prod_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS p1_tot` and so on for other products.

Comment: I tried this approach `SUM(CASE WHEN [prod_id] IN (SELECT [id] FROM [prod_class] WHERE [class] = 1) THEN [qty] ELSE 0 END) AS [p2and3_tot]` but get this error: `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Comment: That won't work since I need to sum the quantity values, not the count of records.

Comment: Will post as an answer cause of formatting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the sample data provided for the `orders` table and created the `product_class` table from the description in the 2nd paragraph of the question.

**Sample Data:**

```
create table #orders
    (
        order_id int
        , prod_id int
        , qty int
    )

create table #product_class
    (
        id int
        , class int
    )

insert into #orders
values (1, 1, 2)
    , (1, 1, 4)
    , (1, 3, 1)
    , (2, 1, 1)
    , (2, 2, 2)
    , (3, 4, 1)
    , (3, 4, 2)
    , (3, 2, 3)
    , (3, 3, 5)
    , (4, 1, 2)
    , (4, 2, 3)
    , (4, 3, 3)
    , (4, 4, 3)
    , (4, 6, 2)

insert into #product_class
values (1, 1)
    , (2, 2)
    , (3, 2)
    , (4, 3)
    , (6, 3)
```

**Answer:**

Starting with the first query written in the question as inspiration, I changed the reference to the `product_class` table to an `inner join` and added the `class` to the `group by`. After that, all that needs to happen is a [`pivot`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the `class`es to go across the columns instead of the rows.

```
select b.order_id
, isnull(b.[1], 0) as c1_tot
, isnull(b.[2], 0) as c2_tot
, isnull(b.[3], 0) as c3_tot
from (
    SELECT o.[order_id]
    , pc.class
    , SUM(o.[qty]) AS [c2]
    FROM [#orders] as o
    inner join #product_class as pc on o.prod_id = pc.id
    GROUP BY o.[order_id]
    , pc.class
    ) as a
pivot (max(a.c2) for a.class in ([1], [2], [3])) as b
```

Output matches the desired output exactly.

Answer (score 0):

A CASE statement might be what you need to do it in a simple query.

```
SELECT  [order_id],
      SUM(CASE WHEN prod_id = 1 THEN qty ELSE 0) AS p1_tot,
      SUM(CASE WHEN prod_id = 2 OR prod_id = 3 THEN qty ELSE 0) AS p2and3_tot,
      SUM(CASE WHEN prod_id = 4 OR prod_id = 6 THEN qty ELSE 0) AS p4and6_tot  
FROM [orders] 
    INNER JOIN [product_class] ON [orders].[prod_id] = [product_class].[id]
WHERE [product_class].[class] = 2
GROUP BY [order_id];
```

Comment: Works great until you need to pull in the prod_id values from a subquery to a product class table. Then you get the error `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `need to pull in the prod_id values from a subquery to a product class table`

Comment: If your product_id is in a different table, then you can try to join instead of using a sub query.

Comment: Made question clearer regarding where the product IDs are coming from.

Comment: You can use inner join and put the condition in the where clause.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: This won't account for the case where a new product is added to a specific class... It also only will work for one product class at a time, instead of three columns with one class in each one.

Comment: It should be able to handle that as well as the sub query. Unless I'm not understanding it correctly.